# Is this correct? "Were these activities being done on the basis of the instructions on the textbooks?"

Tags: tense

> Were these activities being done on the basis of the instructions on the textbooks?

I'm doing a questionnaire, does this question make sense? Perhaps the 'being' is wrong?

Comment: @Lambie Your comment seems the most appropriate way to phrase this; it should go as an answer. Questions in a questionnaire should be kept as short and clear as possible, which your comment does nicely. I don't like the wordiness of the upvoted answer "carried out on the basis of the instructions in the text books".

Answer (score 4):

It would be more idiomatic to ask:

> Were these activities (being) **carried out** on the basis of the instructions **in** the text books?

or more simply:

> Were these activities (being) carried out according to the instructions in the text books?

Comment: so why do we need the "being" here? or why it can be omitted? what tense is that i'm kinda confused lol

Comment: @Angyang, your comment could be the subject of another question. Btw, either the presence or the omission of the **being** has nothing to do with the tense of the sentence.

Comment: As Lucian says; It's a question of nuance. Immediately after the event, I might ask someone: **Was my son being rude to you?** If the event was some time ago, I would omit **being**. The meaning stays the same but **being** implies a certain period of time, however brief.

Comment: @RonaldSole: It's not so much whether the event was "some time ago". More to do with whether *at time of speaking*, the (past) time when that rudeness ***might*** have occurred is in fact the centre of attention (in a non-conversational context, what we'd call the "narrative reference time"). Even if the (possible) rudeness was actually several months or even *years* ago, you might still include ***being*** if you'd been talking about the relevant occasion / date before asking that question.

Answer (score 1):

For a questionnaire:

- **Were these activities being done [by students] based on textbook instructions**?.
  OR
- **Were students *doing these activities* based on textbook instructions**?

There does not seem any reason to use the passive here so I would rewrite it as an active verb.

students do activities, they don't "carry them out".

Things are done **based on** x.

"instructions *on* textbooks" is not accurate. That would mean instructions about textbooks.

What is meant is instructions in textbooks, which can be shortened to:
textbook instructions.